# Intel (R) Virtualization Technology and Intel (R) VT-d Feature

Tags: bios, virtualization, vmware-workstation

Intel (R) Virtualization Technology and Intel (R) VT-d Feature are in the BIOS.

Both are by default enabled.

I use VMWare Workstation for virtualization in the laptop but I am not sure about both.

Please let me know,

1. How both are different?
2. If I disable, Intel (R) VT-d Feature, what can be issue?
3. If I disable Intel (R) Virtualization Technology, what can be issue?
4. In which situation Intel (R) Virtualization Technology or Intel (R) VT-d Feature is required?

With Regards
Rohan

Comment: For VMware Workstation, the settings work together to allow a 64-bit guest to be installed and work. Removing these will not affect the host, but will preclude running a 64-bit guest.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_(VT-x)

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Answer (score 1):

For VMware Workstation, the settings work together to allow a 64-bit guest to be installed and work. Removing these will not affect the host, but will preclude running a 64-bit guest.

I am using this technology on my own ThinkPad with VMware Workstation installed and several 64-bit guests.

Please see:

[VT-D discussion](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-VT-d-and-VT-x-in-virtualization-BIOS-settings)

> VT-x is the generic virtualization of the CPU. EPT is a feature that
> is usually enabled together with VT-x (doesn’t even have a separate
> function visible, not even sure if you can toggle it independently in
> the hardware) that allows proper virtualization (VT-x without EPT
> cannot virtualize 64-bit OS properly)
>
> VT-d is used to implement something called PCIe Passthrough. That is,
> the virtual machine has direct access to a host PCIe device. Typically
> it is a GPU that is passed through for performance issues.
>
> Intel vtx allows for several advantages, but first we should look at
> how virtualization works.
>
> A key aspect of virtualization is such that there is no emulation of
> computational instruction. To give you an idea of what this entails,
> think of an NES emulator. The NES ran on a different architecture than
> your computer currently does. Instructions must be translated from
> it’s architecture to run correctly on your computer. Thus, any
> instruction must have an equivalent software function that calls
> appropriate system calls in the operating system. This incurs
> significant computational overhead.
>
> Virtualization, on the other hand, allows for the guest operating
> system to utilize translation via native registers. This doesn’t
> require redesigned software functions to translate operating system
> functions.

So a key difference: virtualization is largely hardware dependent, emulation is largely software dependent.